# Using JavaScript to detect mobile devices and using the outcome to use the query for mobile devices?

Tags: javascript, web

After some research, I've found that you are able to detect mobile device browsers using this code in JavaScript:

The fact that a lot of devices nowadays have the resolutions of desktop monitors makes it a little more difficult and I can't just using smaller resolutions for mobile devices.

```
var isMobile = {
Android: function() {
    return navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i);
},
BlackBerry: function() {
    return navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i);
},
iOS: function() {
    return navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i);
},
Opera: function() {
    return navigator.userAgent.match(/Opera Mini/i);
},
Windows: function() {
    return navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/WPDesktop/i);
},
any: function() {
    return (isMobile.Android() || isMobile.BlackBerry() || isMobile.iOS() || isMobile.Opera() ||          
isMobile.Windows()); 
 }
};

if( isMobile.any() ) alert('Mobile');
```

This seems quite a logical way to detect mobile devices but I'm not quite sure on the syntax of, after the detection, plugging in the query targeted for smaller devices?

Comment: "plugging in the query..." What query?

Comment: A mobile device query that I had made in CSS. I was wondering how I could use that specific query once JS had detected that it was a mobile device?

Comment: I think you'd be better off being responsive to screen geometry and to whether the device supports touch events. "Mobile" doesn't really mean much.

Comment: Supporting touch events could be a better way come to think of it..

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your need, [media queries](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp) may prove useful.
They allow you to apply different CSS rules depending on the size of the browser viewport.